# multidimensional tableselect

Tags: forms

Is it possible to create a multidimensional tableselect (table with checkboxes)?
Why? I would like to show a tableselect of all menu links to delete one or more but a nested tableselect.

So if they want to delete a link, all child-links will be selected to. I know i can just delete all children with a query, but for the user I want to visualise which part of the tree will be deleted.

Output ex.:
=> CB = checkbox

- CB link1

  - CB  link 2
  - CB  link 3

    - CB  link 4
  - CB  link 5
- CB link 6
- CB link 7

  - CB  link 8

... and so on.

Comment: Yes it's possible, no Drupal doesn't have anything like that built in - so you'd need to implement something custom

Comment: how do you mean ? => i'm a little new in module development

Comment: I mean Drupal has a table select element built in, but it's one-dimensional, so it won't work for your purposes. You could look at extending that element, or use the code for it as a starting point for your own. It's not a small task though, probably better to break it down into the individual development elements (once you've decided what those are) and ask questions about those. Or maybe there's a module already, but in not familiar with one

Comment: ow, yes i knew that. I just wasn't sure it was possible to make it multidimensional. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to delete children as well with parent menu items seems like [Delete menu options](https://drupal.org/project/delete_menu_options) address this issue..

Project page says

> On the 'Delete menu item' confirmation page you can choose to delete
>   child menu items and decide if the linking nodes should be deleted as
>   well. When the checkbox 'Delete all children of this menu.' is
>   checked, all child menu items of the parent menu item to delete, will
>   be deleted as well. When the checkbox 'Delete nodes of the deleted
>   menu items (only orphaned nodes).' is checked, the nodes to which the
>   child menu items link will be deleted too. When other menu items link
>   to same nodes or aliases as the nodes which were set out to be
>   deleted, those nodes will not be deleted.